# Permutations II from leetcode solution

Tags: python, algorithm, reinventing-the-wheel

> Given a collection of numbers that might contain duplicates, return
>   all possible unique permutations.
>
> For example, [1,1,2] have the following unique permutations: 
>   [[1,1,2], [1,2,1], [2,1,1]]

There are many better solutions out there but I am interested in just the code review and how it can be made better.

Solution is exactly described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240080/generating-all-permutations-of-a-given-string)

Let's use input abc as an example.

Start off with just the last element (c) in a set (["c"]), then add the second last element (b) to its front, end and every possible positions in the middle, making it ["bc", "cb"] and then in the same manner it will add the next element from the back (a) to each string in the set making it:

"a" + "bc" = ["abc", "bac", "bca"]  and  "a" + "cb" = ["acb" ,"cab", "cba"] 
Thus entire permutation:

["abc", "bac", "bca","acb" ,"cab", "cba"]

```
class Solution(object):
    def permuteUnique(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """
        if not nums or len(nums) == 1:
            return [nums]
        output_list, output_list_copy, temp_output = [], [], []
        for num in nums:
            if not output_list:
                output_list = [[num]]
                continue
            for t in output_list:
                assigned, already_seen = False, None
                for j in range(len(t)+1):
                    if already_seen == num and assigned:
                        continue
                    t1 = t[0:j] + [num] + t[j:]
                    if j < len(t) and t[j] == num:
                        assigned, already_seen = True, num
                    temp_output.append(t1)
                output_list_copy += temp_output
                temp_output = []
            output_list = output_list_copy
            output_list_copy = []
        return output_list
```

Comment: Is there a reason not to use `itertools.permutations`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is too late for this but it is a good idea to use the "reinvent the wheel" tag for questions like this where you write your own version of an already existing function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a few pointers,

- Use libraries when possible,  you are currently reinventing the wheel of `itertools.permutations`
- You could [use a `set()` to have \$O(N)\$ lookup](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) when finding items that are already seen.
- You should use generators instead of keeping everything in a list, this avoids high memory usage when working with large numbers

**Reinventing the wheel**

```
class Solution:
    def permuteUnique(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: List[List[int]]
        """

        def unique_perms(elements, unique):
            if len(elements) <=1:
                yield elements
            else:
                for perm in unique_perms(elements[1:], unique):
                    for i in range(len(elements)):
                        next_perm = perm[:i] + elements[0:1] + perm[i:]
                        if tuple(next_perm) not in unique:
                            unique.add(tuple(next_perm))
                            yield next_perm

        return list(unique_perms(nums, set()))
```

**Using modules**

```
from itertools import permutations

def permute_unqiue(nums, r):
    return list(set(permutations(nums, r)))
```

This works by making a `set()` of the permutations. That removes all duplicate values, since they will hash to the same thing. Afterwards you can return the `list()` of unique permutations.

Comment: I knew this but just wanted to implement it as person who would be asking this would like to know how to do it given a language which doesn't have this API. Anyway will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

Ludusposed's answer is excellent but it can still be improved. Indeed, [you don't need a class](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0).

Comment: Good point, but many (most?) online judges require that you wrap the solution in a class.

Comment: That class is necessary on leetcode, where the challenge comes from.

Comment: It is a torture to listen to the  man on the video (he makes me feel I am suffocating in water)

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ Haha, I quite enjoyed the video last time I watched it but your comment made me laugh :)